# Are sums of 0-1 Pareto efficient vectors Pareto efficient?

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, linear-programming, game-theory, recreational-mathematics

Does there exist $m,n\ge1$, an $m \times n$ matrix $A$, and a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that:

- The entries of $A$ are $\in \{0, 1\}$.
- For all pairs of columns $u, v$ of $A$ the entries of $u - v$ are never either all non-negative or all non-positive (i.e. there is a positive entry and a negative entry in $u - v$).
- $\sum_i x_i = 0$.
- The entries of $Ax$ are all non-negative with at least one entry being strictly positive.

Edit: It turns out this is not true via a concrete counterexample found by my collaborator. I would list it, but it's rather large.

Comment: Is the question whether there exist any n,m, such that there is such a matrix? (in contrast to the way Per Alexandersson answered?)

Comment: Yes, I did mean whether there exists such an $n$ and $m$. I only said that to stress that $A$ need not be square. I guess it's still worded a bit unclearly.

Comment: Have you done any computer searches for small m and n?

Comment: Not me personally, but my collaborator tried that.

Comment: I guess $x$ has $n$ entries, not $m$ entries as you have it.

Comment: I'm also guessing your collaborator found an example rather than a counterexample. How large is it?

Answer (score 1):

Not if $n$ is too large compared to $m$: 
For a fixed number of rows, there is only a finite set of possible columns, $2^m$.
Thus, if $n > 2^n$, some columns are identical. This contradicts property 2.

Using a finer reasoning about the second constraint, it should be easy to strengthen this observation.

*As a related and easier problem:* 
What is the maximal size of a subset of $\{0,1\}$-vectors of length $n$,
such that all pairs satisfy property 2?

Comment: The $n$ and $m$ were stated to just indicate that $A$ need not be rectangular --- they're numbers given to us.

Comment: Ah, ok, that makes more sense then.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I have misunderstood, here is a counterexample. Let $A$ be the $2\times 2$ identity matrix. This has your Pareto property on $x-y$, but if $x=[{a\atop b}]$, then $Ax=x$, and there is no way to have both $a+b=0$ and both $a$ and $b$ non-negative with at least one positive.

Comment: I guess my question was worded a bit poorly, but I was wondering if there ever exists such an $A$ and an $x$ pair. I've edited my question to reflect that now.